# node.js changes made in files not reflecting until the second run

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am converting all `.png` files to `.jpg` files in a directory and then running some manipulations on them which can be only to to `jpeg` files. But `node.js` doesn't seem to notice the converted files and the deleted png files until I run the same script again.

```
    const fs = require('fs')
    const pngToJpeg = require('png-to-jpeg');

    let dirrCont = fs.readdirSync( dir );

    files = dirrCont.filter( ( elm ) => /.*\.(png|jpg)/gi.test(elm) );


    for (i in files)
    {  
        let file = files[i]
        let file_name_without_ext = file.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")
        let extension = file.match(/\.[^/.]+$/)
        if (extension[0] == '.png')
        {
            console.log('found')
            let buffer = fs.readFileSync(dir+file);
            pngToJpeg({quality: 100})(buffer)
            .then(output => fs.writeFileSync(dir+file_name_without_ext+'.jpg', output));
            fs.unlinkSync(dir+file)
            extension = '.jpg'
        }
        let target_file = target + file_name_without_ext + '.' + suffix  + extension

    // do some manipulations on dir+file_name_without_ext+extension
```

I always receive the error that the new jpg files are not found thus the manipulations don't work although the `png` files get converted to `jpg` files. When I run the same script again since now all the files are `jpeg` the file manipulations run this time.

## EDIT

as suggested in one of the answers by @CertainPerformance
I changed the code to do most of my stuff inside the then block but again hit the same error

```
for (i in files)
{  
    let file = files[i]
    let file_name_without_ext = file.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")
    let extension = file.match(/\.[^/.]+$/)
    if (extension[0] == '.png')
    {
        console.log('found')
        let buffer = fs.readFileSync(dir+file);
        pngToJpeg({quality: 100})(buffer)
        .then(output => {
        fs.writeFileSync(dir+file_name_without_ext+'.jpg', output);
        extension = '.jpg'

        //
        let target_file = target + file_name_without_ext + '.' + suffix  + extension
        // Do some manipulations
        // I am done with the manipulations and I now want to delete
        // the jpg file I just created
        fs.unlinkSync(dir+file_name_without_ext+'.jpg') // Gives me back the same error
        });
    }
```

**NOTE:** There is a little bit of change up in the edit and I am deleting the `jpg` file instead of the `png` file (which I was doing originally)

Comment: To start with debugging, you might check to see what happens when you call `unlinkSync` right after `writeFileSync`, just to simplify matters a bit. I wonder if files created via `writeFileSync` are actually created immediately, or if it takes a few milliseconds for them to be visible and able to be worked with. (maybe try setting a short `setTimeout`, see what happens?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance the manipulations I run, I am using the jimp library and that surely requires the file to be present

Comment: @CertainPerformance but the timeout thing works

Comment: Because the library requires the file to be present, but the error is thrown when you call `unlinkSync` later, it sounds like the code that's causing the problem is somewhere in your `Do some manipulations` - perhaps the file gets deleted inside of it, which is why `unlinkSync` then doesn't work. `unlinkSync` *should* work even if right after `writeFileSync`.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see by the `.then`, `pngToJpeg` is asynchronous - if you want to do work on `dir+file_name_without_ext`, you have to wait for the initial `.then` and the `writeFileSync` to resolve first. Put everything that depends on the asynchronous operations inside the `then`. For example:

```
if (extension[0] == '.png') {
  console.log('found');
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(dir + file);
  pngToJpeg({ quality: 100 })(buffer)
    .then(output => {
      fs.unlinkSync(dir + file);
      fs.writeFileSync(dir + file_name_without_ext + '.jpg', output);
      extension = '.jpg';
      const target_file = target + file_name_without_ext + '.' + suffix + extension;
      // do some manipulations on dir+file_name_without_ext+extension
    });
}
```

(You should also take care not to implicitly create global variables. For example, use `for (const i in files)` instead, or perhaps `for (const file of files)` to avoid having to fiddle with the unimportant indicies)

Comment: Good advice. Would you mind explaining the second part, why would it be a better idea to use `for (const file in files)` or `for (const file of files)` and what are the differences between the two?

Comment: When you have an array, `for..of` will iterate over the array's *values*, whereas `for..in` iterates over the array's *indicies*. If you're only using the array's values, and you only care about the indicies so that you can get at the values, use `for..of` instead. (Or, even better, use an array method such as `forEach`)

Comment: Thats amazing. Thank you for explaining, I never knew

Comment: I added an **EDIT** to the question, your solution helped me but not entirely, there is still some thing happening that I don't get and deleting the `jpg` file back inside the `then` gives me the ***file not found*** error again

Comment: more specifically `(node:98477) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,`